# File ‘mpi.mod’ opened at (1) is not a GNU Fortran module file

Tags: fortran, mpi, gfortran, mpich

I'm trying to compile RegCM4.5 my configuration looks like have no errors but while compiling (by `make` command) I get this error

```
File ‘mpi.mod’ opened at (1) is not a GNU Fortran module file
```

I have installed `mpich` by `dnf install` package manager. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Comment: @Toby a MCVE will be very likely just `use mpi; end`.

Comment: Do you have any other Fortran compilers installed? Do you know which compiler was used to compile MPICH? Could you try to compile a program which contains `use mpi` and nothing else?

Comment: dear Vlademir thanks for your attention. I dont know which compiler is used for MPICH! how can I know this? and I didnt get what you meant with use mpi !!! can you please give me more guide?

Comment: Try the program I requested.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem recently. The problem was that I had different versions of the gfortran compiler and openmpi was not pointing to the right one, aka. the one being used for compiling my program. So using the `use mpi` statement would lead to that error. Typing in the following command will indicate which Fortran compilers are currently installed:

```
dpkg -l | grep Fortran
```

My output was

```
ii  gfortran                                    4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1                              amd64        GNU Fortran 95 compiler
ii  gfortran-4.8                                4.8.5-4ubuntu2                                amd64        GNU Fortran compiler
ii  gfortran-5                                  5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04                          amd64        GNU Fortran compiler
ii  libgfortran-4.8-dev:amd64                   4.8.5-4ubuntu2                                amd64        Runtime library for GNU Fortran applications (development files)
ii  libgfortran-5-dev:amd64                     5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04                          amd64        Runtime library for GNU Fortran applications (development files)
ii  libgfortran3:amd64                          6.2.0-3ubuntu11~16.04                         amd64        Runtime library for GNU Fortran applications
```

You can solve this by exporting the fortran compiler you are actually using. In my case it was gfortran-4.8, so I simply had to type

```
export FC=gfortran-4.8
```